# Does Android support Wi-Fi Management Frame Protection?

Tags: wi-fi

I am trying to find out whether Android supports Wi-Fi Management Frame Protection.
From my understanding, this is standardized in IEEE 802.11w, so if Android supports that, it also supports MFP.

However, I can't find any source on whether Android supports this or not. I found some articles about it but they only mentioned specific phones, and not the entire Android specification. The [Android Source Docs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-overview?hl=en) don't say anything on this, and the [Android Enterprise Security Whitepaper](https://storage.googleapis.com/android-com/resources/enterprise/pdfs/AE%20Security%20Paper_V6%20CM.pdf) only states that Android supports WPA3, Wi-Fi Enhanced Open, and 802.11i.

Do you know whether Android supports MFP or not?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11w-2009#Usage it is implemented in "recent Linux kernels" (the sentence seems to be added some years ago so most likely it has been already taken over by Android). So should check if the compile flag(s) that enables this implementation is active in the standard Android kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Robert s suggestion, I dug deeper to find out if Android uses a linux kernel with MFP enabled.

I found [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/1b7cc21fb2978434151423fa496b3a50acca7cdb) commit to the Android source code, which enabled PMF (= Protected Management Frames = Management Frame Protection) in January 2014:

> Android: Enable 802.11w (PMF) support in wpa_supplicant

I also found out on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access#WPA3) that WPA3 (which Android supports) requires MFP:

> Protection of management frames as specified in the IEEE 802.11w amendment is also enforced by the WPA3 specifications.

So yes, Android supports Management Frame Protection.